# Mule startup order for applications

Tags: mule

So, i have three mule applications where one needs to be started before the other two. And I start mule as a windows service. I found this [site](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Start-Mule-application-before-the-rest-of-the-applications) and follow the example by putting

```
wrapper.app.parameter.1=-app
wrapper.app.parameter.2=%MULE_STARTUP_ORDER%
```

in wrapper.conf. where MULE_STARTUP_ORDER is an system variable containing App1:App2:App3

But when i look in my mule.log after staring the service app2 starts first followed by app3 and app1 is last.

And I use mule standalone 3.7.0.

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the list of applications directly in wrapper.conf in case the service has no access to the system environment variable from Windows. Also try using higher numbers for the parameters like the example in the KB article you referenced. Low numbers might be get overridden by other parameters.

Example:

```
wrapper.app.parameter.10=-app
wrapper.app.parameter.20=app1:app2:app3
```

Comment: Adding `parameter.1` definitely did not work for me. It had to be `app.parameter.10` (Mule 3.9)